# How to make javascript created image a link

Tags: javascript

Hey there I am not very fluent with javascript and jquery.
I want to replace a div with an image when clicked on one div and make that image clickable i.e. I want to add link to that image.

To get this I am using a javascript

```
function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {      

        var container = document.getElementById(id);
        container.innerHTML = content;
}
```

I am calling this javascript from my index.ctp file as

```
<div id="vedio-image">   
                    </div>

        <div class="title"> 
                                        <a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('vedio-image',
                                           '<img width=\'480px\' height=\'220px\' src=\'<?php echo $this->webroot.'img/'.$count['News']['videoImage']; ?> \'/ >')">
                                          <?php  echo $count['News']['title'];?>  
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

ReplaceContentInContainer is working perfectly but I am not able to make that image clickable.
Please can anyone help.

Comment: You didn't write `onclick` in `<img>` tag, or not surround your `<img>` tag with `<a>` tag

Comment: Also, you're not using jQuery.

Comment: That's considered a problem nowadays? :)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor You're probably right! You could totally turn that into an answer, make a fiddle, and enjoy some upvotes...

Comment: @OneTrickPony No one said that it was a problem =/ He says in his question that he isn't fluent in JavaScript **and jQuery**. The OP isn't using jQuery, just pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write `onclick` in `<img>` tag, or not surround your `<img>` tag with `<a>` tag

Change the HTML code to :

```
<div id="vedio-image"></div>
<div class="title"> 
  <a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('vedio-image',
                                           '<a href=\'http://example.com\'><img width=\'480px\' height=\'220px\' border=\'0\' src=\'<?php echo $this->webroot.'img/'.$count['News']['videoImage']; ?> \' /></a>')">
  <?php  echo $count['News']['title'];?></a>
</div>
```

*sidenote:* I added `border="0"` to avoid a blue border appearing in IE.

Comment: thanks a lot Shivan Raptor as I told I am not good in javascript at all....Thanks a lots its a great help